# C++ possible to call function with same name in different class with single pointer?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to call run() with p without concerning different class they are(for example class cast on a void*) and different implementation of run() in each class?

```
class A
{
    void func()
    {
        //new B
        //new C
        //new D
        //*p points to the instance of one of B,C,D
        p->run(i);
    }
    // some pointer *p
}

class B
{
    void run(int i);
}

class C: public B
{
    void run(int i);
}

class D: public B
{
    void run(int i);
}
```

Comment: What about inheritance and corral a virtual functions?

Comment: But you still need to store the child class in multiple point with different type or a single void* and cast it later, right?

Comment: No. What you want is called polymorphism. You can simply store a `B*`. That `B*` can also point to an `C` or `D`, because any `C` _is_ a `B` and any `D` _is_ a `B`. In that case you'd need to make `run` virtual though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
    public:
    virtual int run(int i);
};

class A
{
    public:
    int func(B* obj, int i)
    {
        return obj->run(i);
    }
};



class C: public B
{
    public:
    virtual int run(int i){ return 2*i;}
};

class D: public B
{
    public:
    virtual int run(int i){ return 3*i;}
};

int main(){
    A a;

    C obj1;
    D obj2;

    B* ptr1 = &obj1;
    B* ptr2 = &obj2;

    std::cout << a.func(ptr1, 3) << "\n";
    std::cout << a.func(ptr2, 3) << "\n";
}
```